# Set TextView width to 0dp doesn't work

Tags: android, textview

How to set programmatically width of TextView to be 0dp ? I am trying to put in LinearLayout couple TextViews but all to be same width, and when I put in xml like

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
 <TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:gravity="left"
                    />
 <TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
 <TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="test"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:gravity="right"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

but when in code try like

```
TextView txtTemp = new TextView(this);
txtTemp.setText(captures.get(i));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tempLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) txtTemp
                        .getLayoutParams();
tempLL.width =0;
tempLL.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
tempLL.weight = 1;

if (i == 0) {
    tempLL.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        }
if (i == (captures.size() - 1)) {
    tempLL.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
} else {
    tempLL.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                }
    txtTemp.setLayoutParams(tempLL);
```

I got exception on tempLL.width  null exception. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tempLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) txtTemp
                    .getLayoutParams();
            tempLL.width =0;
            tempLL.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            tempLL.weight = 1;
```

try this

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams tempLL = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0);
txtTemp.setLayoutParams(tempLL);
```

You are creating a new textview and there is no layoutparams specified yet. So getLayoutParams should return null. So create a new layoutparam object and set that to the new textview.

Comment: The above soln helped me to squeeze the width of  my ListView.But, I would also like to squeeze my height of listview. will there be any option?

Comment: By squeeze, if you mean fill the outer container, you might need to nest your listview in another linearlayout with the height filling the outer container.