# Programmatically set button width to 50% of parent LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I created a Dialog using LinearLayout and in this Dialog, I have a Button. I want to set its width to 50% of the Dialog's width, but no matter what I do, the button is still filling the entire width. The main problem seems to be that I cannot set the button's weight programmatically. I tried creating a second horizontal LinearLayout that would hold the button with weight set to 0.5f (the parent has a weightSum of 1), but that did not change anything. How can I set the button to be half the width?

I've looked at all the other questions but most of them were using xml so they were not relevant, and the one that solved it programmatically was using hardcoded values in pixels which is obviously an incorrect solution to the problem.

EDIT: Adding some code

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
linearLayout.setWeightSum(1);

// I use these params when I call addContentView
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

testButton = new Button(mContext);
testButton.setText("Test");
testButton.setId(1);
testButton.setWidth(0);
testButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

LinearLayout buttonLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
butonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
testButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
buttonLayout.addView(testButton);

linearLayout.addView(buttonLayout);

...

this.addContentView(scrollView, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I tried more and more options, the code became a mess. I decided to start from scratch and this code worked in the end:

```
LinearLayout forButton = new LinearLayout(mContext);
forButton.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams forButtonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
forButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
this.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;

forButton.addView(testButton);
testButton.getLayoutParams().width = width/2;
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you setting the width value to 0dp as well?  This is required for the layout engine to automatically to use layout weight respectively.

**Edit**

I think this line will get you the results you are looking for:

```
LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f);
```

Comment: Please use the comment feature for asking clarifying questions.

Comment: @Siddharth Lele thanks for the comment, but while it's framed as a question, if true will likely be the answer to the original question.

Comment: I did that in one of the past attempts, but let's try again.

Comment: @AndroidAddict: In that case, my bad. :-(. I was on the line on that one.

Comment: tried again and nope, the button is still wide. I guess it is somehow caused by the MATCH_PARENT, but I have no idea how to bypass it.

Comment: @JohnEye you are setting the width to wrap_content in the parms.  You cannot do this and have the layout engine resize - you must set width to 0dp for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, but setting the first value to 0 causes the whole Dialog to shrink to a spaghetti. Including all the other elements inside it.

Comment: Are you setting it on the button or the container?  This should be applied to the button.

Comment: When I set it on the button, it is still wide. If I set it on the container, it shrinks.

Comment: I am at a loss then because this same solution can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784579/set-textview-width-to-0dp-doesnt-work

Comment: I needed to set a Spinner width to be a certain percentage of its parent, and this worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To find dialog width

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels ;
```

To Set Value programmatically

```
final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(Height,width/2); // Width , height
    final Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

**EDIT**

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

lp.copyFrom(alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = 200;
lp.height = 200;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that set the button width to half the width of screen, instead of half the width of its parent dialog?

Comment: dialog.getWindow will get the dialog window parameters and yes you need to set the parent layout's parameters as fill parent

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't guarantee that the Dialog will fill the window, for example in Android 4.

Comment: the above code will give you the parameters of Dialog which your showing and not the width of entire screen please give it a try

Comment: Thank you, this is working, kinda. The button is indeed less wide, but the damned Dialog shrinks now to the same width as the button.

Comment: set the height and width parameter of your dialog  i.e if you want it to be 200x200 check edit how to do it, please accept it as answer if it helps

Comment: It is currently set to MATCH_PARENT, so the behavior is weird.

Comment: your dialog will depend on the content size I think you only have a Button inside it thats y Dialog size is equal to button you need to try the code in Edit it will set the Dialog height and width to a value you wish then you will get the desired output