# android set width and height to 100% of a dynamically created button

Tags: android, layout, height, width

that might be a silly question but i didn't find any answer on the internet.

I want to create a button that fills the whole screen (width = 100%, height = 100%) when pressing another button.

Therefore i tried this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setText("fills screen");
button.setWidth(100);
button.setHeight(100);
```

the problem is that the setWidth and setHeight methods are dealing with px and not with percent.

What do i need to add to use percent values instead of px values?

Comment: Do you want to fill whole screen with button or only the parent layout?

Answer (score 0):

I'll link here a post that details how to set a width programmatically 
[programmatically set button width to 50 of parent linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069882/programmatically-set-button-width-to-50-of-parent-linearlayout)

You can utilize that method (except do not divide by 2 JohnEye demonstrates in his answer)

Or you can utilize the `LayoutParams` class and create a new instance that will have the parameters set and pass those parameters to your object.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
button.setLayoutParams(lp); // Assuming you've already initiated it of course as above
```

MATCH_PARENT will fill up the view. If the root view is the highest view on the hierarchy then this will work, as it will fill up the entire view. If not, the button would need to be moved there. (It may be your linearLayout or some other view)

Hope this helps.